# "This result object does not return rows" error with pandas .read_sql()

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am trying to simply delete records that are from the previous month in a sql table.

`df_month_exist = pd.read_sql(''' DELETE FROM DATATABLE WHERE RECORD_MONTH = DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, -1, GETDATE())-1, -1) ''', con=sqlalchemy)`

no errors when executed in SSMS, but i get this error in python:

sqlalchemy.exc.ResourceClosedError: This result object does not return rows. It has been closed automatically.

I am using sqlalchemy 2.025, pandas 2.1.4, pyodbc 5.0.1 and SSMS 19.2

I have tried using SET NOCOUNT ON in the sql statement , that did not help.

Answer (score 1):

Your `DELETE` statement does not return rows, so `.read_sql()` is not the right approach. Instead, you should do something like

```py
with engine.begin() as conn:
    conn.exec_driver_sql("DELETE …")
# the statement is committed when the context manager ("with" block) exits
```

Comment: this was great advice. the simplest answer i've found and it works. thank you.